# How to inform former intern boss that I'm re-applying to their company

Tags: professionalism, management, internship, applications

I interned at company X a couple years ago. At the end of the summer, one of my supervisors told me, "Let me know if you'd like to work here after you graduate" (would be happy to have me back, etc.). I recently applied to a position at company X and was notified that I'm in the final stages of the process. I completely forgot to notify him earlier, but feel like I should because a) he told me to and b) perhaps it could help with my application. We were on pretty good terms during the internship, haven't talked to him for a while though. Is there a way of writing this email that doesn't come off in a totally opportunistic way, i.e. only getting back in touch because I need something?

Comment: *"but feel like I should because a) he told me to"* - Actually, you indicated that this person said "let me know if you would like to work here after you graduate", not "let me know if you apply here after you graduate"... I see no "obligation" to tell this person that you are applying

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of writing this email that doesn't come off in a totally opportunistic way, i.e. only getting back in touch because I need something?

To be honest, I see no convincing reason nor need to write this email.

You already at the final stages of the application process, so chances are you will most likely land it. Writing an email to this person may or may not increase your chances further, but it will surely seem a bit opportunistic.

You say you feel compelled to write because "he told you so", however in no way you are *forced* to write to him.

In fact, the *"Let me know if you'd like to work here after you graduate"* was a *suggestion* if you ever wanted to return, but given the fact that you have already applied seems that you missed the timing for that invitation (i.e.: you should have done it before applying by your own means).

*Bottom line:* I suggest you don't write such email and continue your process naturally. If you land the job you can then go greet your former manager in person. If you don't, you can then decide if it's worth to use your contact to see if you can land it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already had a good relationship, feel free to shoot him an email along the lines of

"Hey , how are things going at  I have good news; I applied for a job there and am now in the final stages of the interview. I enjoyed my internship so I'm looking forward to the opportunity to work with  again. I was wondering if you had any advice for me going forward. Thanks, and I hope to see you again soon"

As for not sounding opportunistic, I wouldn't worry about it if I were you. This sort of thing happens all the time in the professional world. But, if you are genuinely interested in catching up, you can invite him to catch up over lunch. He would probably enjoy seeing you again if you had a good relationship before.